# Structure of vectors C++

Tags: vector, struct

is there a way to clear a structure of vectors at a time using a single statement ?
i.e.
struct AStruct
{
  vector StringList;
  vector DistanceList;
}A;

i want both the vectors using a single statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
AStruct a;
// stuff
a = AStruct();  // clear it
```

However, I would probably give myself a function:

```
struct AStruct { 
   vector <string> StringList; 
   vector <string> DistanceList; }
   void clear() {
       StringList.clear();
       DistanceList.clear();
   }
};
```

You can then say:

```
AStruct a;
// stuff
a.clear();  // clear it
```

which is perhaps easier to understand.

Comment: AStruct() is a constructor right ? if I dont want to write a constructor , how can i do it ?

Comment: You don't need to write a constructor - the compiler provides this one for you.