# structure of double vectors

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a structure of double vectors in C++.

```
struct distance{
    vector<double> x(10000);
    vector<double> y(10000);
    vector<double> z(10000);
};

distance distance_old, distance_new;
```

In the definition it throws an error saying:

```
error: expected identifier before numeric constant
error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant
```

Where am I going wrong?

I saw this post [Structure of vectors C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290540/structure-of-vectors-c)
but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: The code in the link works fine, because it doesn't have `(10000)`.  You can't do that there.

Comment: I made the changes as Joachim suggested. I still keep getting the same error, in the same line of struct definition.

Comment: Have you #included <vector> and using namespace stl?

Comment: Also, are you trying to initialize your x,y,z to 10000 or are you trying to create 10000 entries of each?

Comment: Yes I did include them. I am trying to create 10,000 entries of each of them.

Comment: See my edit.  It's a complete solution which I've verified.

Comment: freshmaster: if you did what Joachim suggested, you should not be getting the same error on the same lines.  That's not possible.

Comment: @freshmaster: Also: You've confused us, should `x` be a vector of 10000 doubles, or should `x` be 10000 vectors, each containing many doubles?

Comment: Yes that did fix the error. I did accept it as the answer as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to *construct* the vectors in the structure, which can't be done. You have to do it in a constructor just like a normal class:

```
struct distance
{

    vector<double> x;
    vector<double> y;
    vector<double> z;

    distance()
        : x(10000), y(10000), z(10000)
        { }
};
```

Comment: Since Matt keeps mentioning that his is "confirmed" and "compiles" I figured I'd mention that this compiles as well: http://ideone.com/5TVH1

Answer (score 1):

You can't call the vector contructor in the struct declaration.  Get rid of the (10000) in your struct declaration.  If you want to use the non-default vector constructor to set the vector initial capacity, you need to do that in a constructor of your struct.

Answer (score -4):

A typo, essentially--you need

```
vector<double> x[10000];
...
```

Wrong brackets!

In addition, strictly speaking you are really defining an array of vectors, not double vectors, which would be `vector< vector<double> >`.  Either is fine depending on your purpose.

EDIT: This solution compiles and has no runtime errors with g++.

dist.h:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct my_distance{
    vector<double> x[10000];
    vector<double> y[10000];
    vector<double> z[10000];
};
```

dist.cpp:

```
#include "dist.h"

my_distance distance_old, distance_new;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

NB 'distance' is already used by the STL for something else, so it has to be renamed.

Comment: I changed it, still the same error.
It was working before I made the structure, so I know its not just the brackets.

Comment: @freshmaster In that case, my guess is that either you forgot `#include <vector.h>` or `using std;`.  Without the latter, you would need to write `std::vector`.

Comment: If the code is rewritten with [] then the error will disappear.  My answer is correct, specifically in declaring 'double vectors' in one possible meaning of the phrase.

Comment: The code clearly shows he wants a vector of doubles, not a multidimensional array of doubles.  This code is leading the OP in the completely incorrect direction.

Comment: @Mooing Duck Oh please, 'double vector' is a non-standard phrase, OP is clearly a new programmer and SO user, he could have easily meant what I thought but have just not included the definition.

Comment: -1 Why on earth would anyone create 10000 `vector<double>`s when he needs 3? Making the error message disappear doesn't mean that the error is also gone.

Comment: @FlopCoder Are you serious?  Maybe he wants to define x, y, and z planes, and so is essentially creating corresponding matrices.  That code (corrected) would be one way to do it.

Comment: @MattPhillips It's very clear that he wants to store x, y, and z values in 3 separate `vector`s. That's very straightforward. Why would he need 10000 `vector<double>`s for storing x?

Comment: I don't know what was he psychic about. I did have #include<vector> before and had the using namespace std.
and declaring  was not a complete typo either. Using the Parenthesis was not causing any problem before when I had declared the vectors individually, instead of in a struct.

Comment: @freshmaster yes because when you declare them outside a `struct`, you're actually *constructing* them. But in a `struct`, you're defining the data type, you should *create* them in the *constructor*.

Comment: @freshmaster If you read through the comment-novel to this post, and look at Joachim Pileborg's answer you'll see that there was controversy over what exactly you meant.  I had guessed your intentions correctly (apparently), that's what Michael Dorgan was referring too.

Comment: Although I am less convinced than I was, I still believe that the OP wants a 1-dimensional vector, and thus your answer is incorrect.  However, since it is more vague than it was, I will remove the down-vote until further clarification is proved by the OP.  Also: Don't take down-votes so personally.  It's not that big a deal.

Comment: @MattPhillips: OP clarified that Joachim Pileborg's answer was the correct interpretation.  Please don't take it personally, but it's normal to down-vote incorrect answers.  Everyone is wrong sometimes.  You were right that the question was unclear, and the later comment implied that your interpretation was correct.

Comment: @MooingDuck Ok.  I'm on the same page with you now, all good.